# Why am i getting ORA-01843: not a valid month error?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I've asked this question in the previous post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520216/ora-01843-not-a-valid-month) but its changed since then and i thought it would be better to make it clearer from the start.

I am receiving this error when running a procedure to delete a customer from a customer table.

```
BEGIN 
customers.remove_customer('17023');
END;
```

However when i delete a customer from the customers table a trigger fires which is where i think the problem lies, here is the code for the trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER CUSTOMER_AD
  BEFORE DELETE ON CUSTOMER
  REFERENCING OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
pragma autonomous_transaction;
nPlaced_order_count  NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO nPlaced_order_count
FROM PLACED_ORDER p
 WHERE p.FK1_CUSTOMER_ID = :OLD.CUSTOMER_ID;
IF nPlaced_order_count > 0 THEN
INSERT into previous_customer
(customer_id,
first_name,
last_name,
address)
VALUES
(:old.customer_id,
:old.first_name,
:old.last_name,
:old.address);
END IF;
END CUSTOMER_AD;
```

Now when i delete a customer who has not got a record in the placed_order table the record is deleted fine, the error message occurs when trying to delete a customer who has a record in the placed_order table. Thus i think the error occurs in the trigger as the trigger is only inserting values into the previous_customer table if they have had a record in the placed_order table. But i still don't understand why i get the error message i do?

The customer table has no other triggers on it.
The placed order table has no other triggers on it and neither does the previous_employee

The structure for customers table is :

```
"CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
"LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
"ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(30) 
CONSTRAINT "PK_CUSTOMER" PRIMARY KEY ("CUSTOMER_ID") ENABLE
```

The structure for placed_order is:

```
"ORDER_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ORDER_DATE" VARCHAR2(15), 
"DELIVERY_DATE" VARCHAR2(15), 
"FK1_CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
CONSTRAINT "PK_PLACED_ORDER" PRIMARY KEY ("ORDER_ID") ENABLE

ALTER TABLE  "PLACED_ORDER" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK1_PLACED_ORDER_TO_CUSTOMER" FOREIGN KEY ("FK1_CUSTOMER_ID")
      REFERENCES  "CUSTOMER" ("CUSTOMER_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
```

and the structure for previous_customer is:

```
"CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR2(40), 
"FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
"LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
"ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(30)
```

Anyone got any idea why I'm getting the error message ORA-01843???

The procedure code is:

```
PROCEDURE remove_customer (customer_id VARCHAR2) IS
   ordersCount pls_integer;
BEGIN
   select count(*) into ordersCount
   from placed_order
   where fk1_customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id
   and delivery_date > sysdate;
IF ordersCount > 0
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer currently has a order been delivered and cant be deleted');
ELSE
DELETE FROM customer
WHERE customer.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;
total_customers := total_customers - 1;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Nothing you showed explains the error. Look for code that tries to parse one of the columns `placed_order.delivery_date` and `placed_order.order_date` into an actual date or datetime object.

Comment: Why do you believe that the trigger is the source of the problem?  If there are no `DATE` columns in any of the tables or in the code, it seems highly unlikely that the trigger is causing the error.  Why is the trigger an autonomous transaction?  That is almost certainly a bug.  Though it is probably not the source of this particular bug.

Comment: If the trigger is the problem then just running... delete from customers where id = ... should get the same problem. Does it?

Comment: Hi @JustinCave when i did not have the autonomous transaction line in it threw back placed_order is mutation trigger/function may not be seen.

Comment: @Dave when i run the simple delete for a customer not in the placed_order table it deletes, when i run it with a customer with a record i get 

"ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back
ORA-06512: at "C3283535.CUSTOMER_AD", line 21
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'C3283535.CUSTOMER_AD'"

Comment: @RichardClare - It sounds like you are trying incorrectly to work around a mutating trigger error using autonomous transactions.  That is never advisable.  It sounds like you're putting far more logic in triggers than belongs there-- that logic generally belongs in stored procedures instead.  Not knowing exactly what's going on elsewhere in your system, it's hard to provide much in the way of specifics.  But you need to address the root of the problem, don't just paper over it by scattering autonomous transaction pragmas through your code.

Comment: What else does the `remove_customer` procedure do, and what is the whole error stack when you get the `ORA-01843`?

Comment: @AlexPoole ive added the procedure code in the top for you, it deletes a customer only if they've received their delivery. And im unsure how to find out the whole error stack?

Comment: WRT Richards Comment (which I agree with) check out http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html

Comment: Can you run this... `select * from user_triggers where table_name = 'CUSTOMER';` to confirm you don't have another trigger?

Comment: Given the code as posted, the only thing I can think of is that somehow a row has been created in PLACED_ORDER which has an invalid date in its DELIVERY_DATE column.  Any possibility that rows are being created in PLACED_ORDER with odd things having been done to the DELIVERY_DATE?  (And by "odd" I mean things such as setting the YEAR field of the date to zero).

Comment: Yep @dave only one trigger

Comment: however i think @alexPoole has found the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DELIVERY_DATE` is `VARCHAR2(15)`. Your procedure includes:

```
and delivery_date > sysdate;
```

... which will cause the `delivery_date` values in the table to be implicitly converted to `date` type, based on the NLS_DATE_FORMAT for the session. If you have a 'date' in there which is not in that format then you will get this error. For example if your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is `mm/dd/yyyy` as you said in the previous question and you've previous stored a date in the table as `dd/mm/yyyy`, e.g. '13/05/2013', then it will get this error from the implicit conversion.

It might be somewhat intermittent; if there is no data in `placed_order` for the customer then there will be no dates to (attempt to) convert.

So it's nothing to do with the trigger. The trigger seems to be pointless anyway; why aren't you just inserting into `previous_customer` in this procedure? You can just do this:

```
ELSE
    INSERT INTO previous_customer(customer_id, first_name, last_name, address)
    SELECT customer_id, first_name, last_name, address)
    FROM customer
    WHERE customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;

    DELETE FROM customer
    WHERE customer.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;

    total_customers := total_customers - 1;
END IF;
```

... and drop and forget about the trigger.

You should not store dates in text fields, for exactly this reason. *If* you can't change the `placed_order` field to a `DATE` type - and you really should - you have to assume that the data in their is in a standard format, and it just doesn't match yours in that case you can (as Bob said) force the conversion on your own terms:

```
and to_date(delivery_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') > sysdate
```

... where `dd/mm/yyyy' is the date format that's been used to populate the text field. If it has a time component, and I guess it might from the length, then include that in the mask too:

```
and to_date(delivery_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') > sysdate
```

... although obviously that's now too long for a `varchar2(15)` field, so who knows what you have in there.

Do you really mean `> sysdate` though? I it populated when at item is actually delivered, or does it show expected delivery date? The error is odd and odesn't make it clear if you only can't delete if there are not-yet-delivered orders, or there have been any delivered orders, in which case `delivery_date is not null` might suffice anyway.

Comment: Thus demonstrating why people need to post *all* teh relevant code and not just part of it. Becvause all too often the bit they think is throwing the error isn't.

Comment: So you think it would work if i changed the date's to the same format as the sysdate. As looking at the placed_orders table records are in this format DD/MM/YYYY and from what your saying i need them to be mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: I think the solution would be to perform an explicit date conversion in REMOVE_CUSTOMER - such as `...TO_DATE(delivery_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') > sysdate...`, assuming you can't change DELIVERY_DATE's type to DATE.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: `sysdate` doesn't have a format. You should change the data type of the `placed_order` field to `DATE`. If that is impossible and out of your control, you'd better hope that all the dates you already have are in the same format - and that is tightly controlled at insert time. And then use an explicit date mask for the conversion.

Comment: Could i not just manually change the dates as there are only around 10 rows of data in the table?

Comment: If you cannot change the datatype then consider placing a check constraint on there such as ... check (to_date(my_date,''dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') != date '9999-12-31'). You won't be tripped up by any "February 30th" issues.